# Angular 2 - Component property changes but view does not update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, setinterval

I'm attempting to learn Angular 2.  My understanding is that interpolated items in the view update when their corresponding variable is updated in the model, however in the code below I do not see this behavior.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ai-header',
    templateUrl: 'app/header/header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/header/header.component.css'],
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    currentTime: Date = new Date();

    getCurrentTime(): void{
        let dateTime = new Date();
        let year = dateTime.getFullYear();
        let month = dateTime.getMonth();
        let day = dateTime.getDate();
        let hour = dateTime.getHours();
        let minute = dateTime.getMinutes();
        let second = dateTime.getSeconds();
        dateTime = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
        
        this.currentTime = dateTime;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        setInterval(this.getCurrentTime, 1000);
    }   
}
```

Why is the view not updating when the 'currentTime' property of the component is updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(this.getCurrentTime.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, and I will mark it as such as soon as I am able.  Thank you very much for the quick response.  If you have time  would you mind explaining your answer in more detail?